# is there a possible css trick for this

Tags: css, html, layout

I'm using a podsnack mp3 player. However, every page refresh, refreshes random numerical div ID codes such as `id="cover#some-random-number#`

So it'll show up like this

```
covercontainer80191
covercontainer36190
```

And so forth. What I wanted to do is a display:none to hide the cover side and just display the song titles instead. Is there a way to do this in the CSS?

The code I'm using is actually an `<iframe/>`.

```
<iframe style="border:none;margin-bottom: 5px" src="http://files.podsnack.com/iframe/embed.html?hash=ah3fblli&t=1369709402" width="425" height="320" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Not sure how _well_ (read as _supported_) it'd work, but you may be able to try `div[id^="covercontainer"] { display: none; }` (I've seen similar be used in the font-awesome CSS to detect the `icon-` prefix.)

Answer (score 1):

If it's in an iframe I don't think there's much you can do with only CSS. It's a separate document and won't inherit styles from the parent document.

However, in your case you can do a little trick to accomplish your goals. Wrap the iframe in another element with `overflow:hidden`, then position the iframe in a way that hides the unwanted content:

```
<div>
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

You'll have to tweak the numbers here, but this seemed good for your case:

```
div {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:199px;
    height:260px;
    position:relative;
}

iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:-43px;
    left:-200px
}
```

Demo, with just the playlist displayed: http://jsfiddle.net/sxyXF/

However, the "cover side" also contains the play button, so there's no way to play the tracks.

Comment: Thanks @wesley murch. That is close, but I have a new problem now.

First, I have 2 copies of the same player, except different playlist. Second, My chat room itself uses an iframe as well, so the css is affecting the chat.

I changed div to div.mp3 which helped. But now both mp3 players are stacking above each other. I want the 2nd to be below the 1st. How can I fix this?

Comment: Also, the scrollbar is missing too

Comment: Yes I assumed you'd know to use a more specific selector than `div {}`. Use an `id` on the wrapper divs (a different id for each one) and use the id as your CSS selector (`#myId {}`). As I said, play with the numbers. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sxyXF/5/ Added more width to show the scroll bar. Gotta run, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding your question you want to hide all of these instances...if that's the case you can do this in your CSS to hide them

```
div[class~="covercontainer"]{
display:none;
}
```